# DatePickerDialog with M+number issue in andorid devices

Tags: android, datepicker

I am trying to implement DatePicker for Date of Birth of User

Here is the screenshot i am using
[image]

The code i am using for this

```
private void showDatePicker(final int view_id, final String countryCode) {
    int mYear, mMonth, mDay;
    // Get Current Date

    Locale locale = new Locale("en", countryCode);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    if (view_id == R.id.dob_drop_down) {
                        dobTextView.setText(Tools.formattedDateOfBirth(String.format("%d-%d-%d", dayOfMonth, monthOfYear + 1, year)));
                    } else if (view_id == R.id.partner_dob_drop_down) {
                        partnerDobTextView.setText(Tools.formattedDateOfBirth(String.format("%d-%d-%d", dayOfMonth, monthOfYear + 1, year)));
                    }
                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

    // Show date till current date
    datePickerDialog.setTitle("Date of Birth");
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: currently this issue was found on devices of ANDROID 7.0 i.e., Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 and Samsung C7pro ANDROID 7.0 it shows M09 in place of month ; as you can see in screenshot above

Comment: What happens if you comment this line `datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());`?

Comment: with that it will enable the date after the current date; dates need to be before or the current date